# Was ist das englische Äquivalent zu "lebensphasenorientierter Personalpolitik"?

Tags: german-to-english, technical-terminology

Ich möchte einen Fragebogen bezüglich lebensphasenorientierter Personalpolitik erstellen, sowohl auf englisch als auch auf deutsch. Meine Frage ist nun, ob es im englischen einen Fachbegriff dafür gibt und nicht nur die wörtliche Übersetzung "life-phase-oriented human resource policy".

Wenn ich mit der wörtlichen Übersetzung nach englischen Artikeln suche, bekomme ich nämlich kaum Ergebnisse die inhaltlich "lebensphasenorientierte Personalpolitik" wiederspiegeln.

Comment: Dafür musst du auf English Language Stackoverflow nachfragen.

Comment: @infinitezero Questions on "Translation and non-English languages" are not allowed on english.stackexchange.com

Comment: Why do you only quote the first half? "Translation and non-English languages - please see the [translation tag](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/translation/info) info for details" Following the links gives "This Stack Exchange site is not a translation service. However, the community can try to help with an idiomatic translation of a particular word or phrase. You need to assume that we do not know what it means in the original language: you need to use English to explain the non-English word or phrase."

Comment: @infinitezero thanks, I will ask there as well. However, I don't see how this question is off-topic here. [Quoting here](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1058/30831): "If you completely understand a German word’s meaning and have trouble finding a matching English word, your question is off-topic here and should be asked on a site about the English language (see below). **An exception is if the word’s meaning is so intricate that you cannot satisfyingly describe it with other words.**"

Comment: In the question you provided an English translation, so it's not clear to me why you cannot use that as a basis for a question in English SE.

Comment: @RHa I will ask the question there, and try to formulate a satisfactory definition for the term. Thank you

Comment: I consider ell.stackexchange as the better platform to ask for an english term rather than english.SE.

Comment: When you quote that you feel unable to translate that term, I'd also rather suggest that you edit your question to find a "German workaround" while aiming for an english translation. Bisher steht die Frage nach "englischem Fachbegriff" - und das ist eine Übersetzung, die englische Muttersprachler besser können.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm but this is not about learning the English language but about a technical term.

Comment: Was bedeutet oder verschleiert der Begriff denn auf deutsch ? Ich denke, das wäre vor einem Übersetzungsversuch zu klären. Der Ausdruck regt ja die Fantasie an, aber es kann ja auch schlicht eine Worthülse sein ... :-)

Comment: Ich hatte mit Anfragen dieser Art auf "English Stackexchange" durchaus schon öfters Erfolg. Es geht hier ja nicht um eine simple Übersetzung, die man auch im Wörterbuch nachschauen könnte, sondern um die Suche nach einem situationsangemessenen Ausdruck in einer Fachsprache. Die Frage muss halt entsprechend formuliert sein. Das Thema ist deutlich jenseits von "English Language Learners Stackexchange".

Comment: for those interested, here is the question I posted on the English site: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/529524

Comment: die Frage fand ich sehr interessant und ich hatte viel Spaß mir eine Antwort zu überlegen, da es hier aber geschlossen wurde, habe ich auf die Frage im englischen Stackexchange geantwortet: 

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/529524 

 "Employee-oriented personnel policy"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solche Wortungetüme sind eher eine deutsche Spezialität und im Englischen selten zu finden. Ich bin  nicht vom Fach, aber dass Personalpolitik sehr viele Faktoren des möglichen Personals zu berücksichtigen hat, wie eben das Alter, äh die Lebensphase, Mobilität und Qualifikation, hätte ich vorausgesetzt. Wie sich  Personalpolitik daran *orientieren* kann, erschließt sich mir nicht. Handelt es sich um besondere Rücksichtnahme darauf?

*Life cycle* würde ich jedenfalls vermeiden, das verwendet man eher bei Produkten.

Mit diesem partiellen Verständnis würde ich übersetzen:

> Human resources management focusing on chapter of life

Comment: "focusing on chapter of life". This feels wrong to me. Shouldn't it be "chapters" or "a chapter"?

Comment: @infinitezero: Meine Fundstellen (z. B. [Pons](https://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung/deutsch-englisch/Lebensabschnitt) verwenden alle nur den Singular, und ich ich sehe analog zu qualifikationsorientiert (nicht: qualifikationenorientiert) oder bei einem versuchsweise Ersetzen durch *age* (nicht: *ages*) da auch keinen Änderungsbedarf. Je nach Weiterführung können sich solche Gründe einstellen.

Comment: Dir steht's ja frei den Singular da zu verwenden. Es klingt für mich ohne Artikel trotzdem falsch.